# How do I auto-assign Django ModelForm fields to a CustomUser?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-custom-user

I'm putting a form on the frontend of my website, and I can't figure out how to auto-assign a specific ModelForm field to the currently logged in user. I've created a custom user with email as the unique ID. I can load the page & submit the form fine, but it doesn't save to the logged in user, and I can't see the saved information on the admin. I use a separate model to base my ModelForm off of, and one of the fields is a foreign key that references the email of the CustomUser. I've included my CustomUser Model, a separate model for the ModelForm, the ModelForm itself, and the View.

Any help or suggestion is appreciated! See my code below:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

email = models.EmailField(max_length = 100, unique = True)
first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50, verbose_name='first name')
last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50, verbose_name='last name')
date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True, verbose_name='joined')
last_login = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True, verbose_name='last login')
is_active = models.BooleanField(default = True)
is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_staff = models.BooleanField(default = False)
is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)

objects = CustomUserManager()

USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
REQIURED_FIELDS = []

def get_user_email(self):
    return self.email

def get_user_name(self):
    return str(self.first_name) + str(self.last_name)

def has_perm(self, perm, obj = None):
    return self.is_admin

def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
    return True
```

Model for ModelForm:

```
class FacilityInfo(models.Model):
email = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
num_facilities = models.PositiveBigIntegerField()

num_one = models.URLField(null = False)
num_two = models.URLField(null = True)
num_three = models.URLField(null = True)
num_four = models.URLField(null = True)
num_five = models.URLField(null = True)
num_six = models.URLField(null = True)
num_seven = models.URLField(null = True)
num_eight = models.URLField(null = True)
num_nine = models.URLField(null = True)
num_ten = models.URLField(null = True)

num_one_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50, null = False)
num_two_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50, null = True)
num_three_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50, null = True)
num_four_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50, null = True)
num_five_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50, null = True)
num_six_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50, null = True)
num_seven_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50, null = True)
num_eight_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50, null = True)
num_nine_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50, null = True)
num_ten_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50, null = True)

ess_login = models.CharField(max_length= 200, null = False)
ess_pw = models.CharField(max_length= 200, null = False)
```

ModelForm:

```
class FacilitySetup(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = FacilityInfo
    fields = ('email','ess_login','ess_pw','num_one','num_one_name','num_two','num_two_name')

ess_login = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(
    attrs={
        "placeholder":"Easy Storage Username",
        "class" : "form-control"
    }
))

ess_pw = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(
    attrs={
        "placeholder":"Easy Storage Password",
        "class" : "form-control"
    }
))   

num_facilities = forms.IntegerField(help_text = "# of Facilities")

num_one = forms.URLField(widget = forms.URLInput(
    attrs={
        "placeholder":'Facility 1 URL',
        'class': "form-control"
    }
))

num_one_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(
    attrs={
        "placeholder":"Facility 1 Name",
        "class" : "form-control"
    }
))

num_two = forms.URLField(widget = forms.URLInput(
    attrs={
        "placeholder":'Facility 2 URL',
        'class': "form-control"
    }
))

num_two_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(
    attrs={
        "placeholder":"Facility 2 Name",
        "class" : "form-control"
    }
))

def clean_user(self):
    if not self.cleaned_data['email']:
        return CustomUser()
    return self.cleaned_data['email']
```

View:

```
@loginrequired(login_url="/login/")

def facility_info(request):
msg = None
success = False

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = FacilitySetup(request.CustomUser, request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        obj = form.save(commit=False) # Return an object without saving to the DB
        obj.email = request.CustomUser # Add an author field which will contain current user's id
        obj.save()

        msg = 'Facility Info Succesfully Saved'
        success = True

    else:
        msg = "Fields are not valid"

else:
    form = FacilitySetup()

return render(request, "facilities/settings.html",{"form": form, "msg":msg, "success":success})
```

Comment: Let's start here: Have you set your `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in settings.py?

Comment: Hey @MiloPersic - thanks for the quick response. Yes, I have it set like so:

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.CustomUser'

Comment: HI, just to make sure that there is no error message popping out right? if there is any error message, able to share it so that I can take a look?

Comment: Since you've set the AUTH_USER_MODEL in settings, have you tried using `obj.email = request.user` instead of `obj.email = request.CustomUser` ?

Comment: @MiloPersic I went ahead and changed this and I now when submitting the form, I get this error:

'CustomUser' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: @Shadowwalker - thanks for your question. no error message until now. I made the changes suggested above and now I get the error message, described above

Comment: Sorry, try request.user.email.  Also what happens when you print request.user to the console?

Comment: @MiloPersic I went and changed it but I still get the same error, 'CustomUser' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: What about printing your user to the console, like `print(request.user)` in your view.  Do you get a name for a user or some other info?  It's a little bit hard to tell what's going on.  Try searching for that error message on Stack - there are lots of results for  'CustomUser' object has no attribute 'get'  or  'User' object has no attribute 'get' .

Comment: @MiloPersic I've tried searching Stack for an hour or so with no luck. I'm using Visual Studio code but have having trouble getting an answer when printing 'print(request.user)' in the console.

Comment: @Shadowwalker - have you ever come across this error message? 'CustomUser' object has no attribute 'get'